# Accessing PivotTable settings (For empty cells show) using Java - Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

Is it possible to access that particular Pivot Table settings using Java's Apache Poi, as I need to set blank values in the pivot table to 0 after generating the pivot table. The pivot table will be used to generate the pivot chart using XSSFChart, in which chart.plot is throwing an error "null" because of the settings which are not generated along with the pivot table.

I tried to include the "0" values through code on blank cells, but yet it still display the same error, whereas if I open the sheet which has the pivot table and set the settings manually through the "PivotTable options", the chart is able to generate successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, Aspose has setNullValue. But I am not sure for Apache.

Perhaps the feature will be released in the future.

Till then, I suggest you use Aspose